# Serving files from Vite server.fs does not work in node 18+

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, vite

We've been using node.js 16.16.0 with Vite(our monorepo is managed using rush with pnpm under the hood), and we were serving some files using server.fs configuration(https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-fs-allow).

In node 16.16 everything works as expected, more or less, *allow* option as well as *deny* option serve their purpose. However, after upgrading node to 18.13, the functionality of serving files from filesystem does not work at all, and there is very little to work with.

Every request for specific file, that works in node 16.16 returns with `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5001` where 5001 is our dev port. Host and port are set correctly.No suspicious error messages in the console etc.

It looks like the files are not beeing served under this urls at all. Using *deny* changes nothing, still the response is `ECONNREFUSED`(in 16.16 it's 403 Restricted).

I upgraded Vite to the newest version, error still the same.

I'm slowly running out of ideas, I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found the issue... It's so dummy and has nothing to do with Vite... In node 17+ they are no longer treating IPv4 as default, but they are taking the OS system configuration into account.

```
Node.js no longer re-sorts results of IP address lookups and returns them as-is (i.e. it no longer ignores how your OS has been configured). You can change the behaviour via the verbatim option to dns.lookup() or set the --dns-result-order command line option to change the default.
```

It means that application on this node version will no longer serve anything on 127.0.0.1(IPv4), but on ::1(IPv6). Switching from '127.0.0.1' to 'localhost' did the trick in my case.

Comment: Fyi if you land on this question from search, for us most issues like this were resolved by upgrading Node to 20.